# Push data into existing array using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find a way to build my custom array, but I am not able to do so.

What I have done so far:

1. I have my array constructed like so:

`const super_array = [];`

```
super_array.push({
 produs: rezultate[i].produs,
 email: rezultate[i].email,
 pretDorit: rezultate[i].pretDorit
});
```

2. Further down into the code, I want to assign new data to the array, like so :

   ```
    for(let j=0; j<results.length; j++) {
                priceNumber = parseFloat(results[j].replace('<span>Lei</span>', '')) ;
                super_array.push({price: priceNumber})
            }
   ```

   Result:

Right now, I get the following structure:

```
super_array({
      produs: rezultate[i].produs,
      email: rezultate[i].email,
      pretDorit: rezultate[i].pretDorit
    }, {pret: priceNumber});
```

What I would like to get is:

```
super_array({
      produs: rezultate[i].produs,
      email: rezultate[i].email,
      pretDorit: rezultate[i].pretDorit,
      pret: priceNumber
    });
```

I am not sure if I have explained it correctly. Basically I want to have the priceNumber uniquely match with the other data in the existing array, and not to be added as a separate index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

super_array[0].pret = priceNumber

Comment: You sir are a life saver, you cannot believe of how much time I have banged my head around this. Thank you very much! Happy holidays

Comment: Happy holidays to you

Answer (score 0):

`super_array.push` adds a new object to the array. What you are trying to do in the last code is adding a property to an object of the array.

For example: `super_array[0].pret = priceNumber` will add the property `pret` with the value of `priceNumber`. Here I'm not adding new objects to the array.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, this solved my issue!